# Purpose of 'isUnique' field in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't understand the purpose of fields like `unique` and `required` in Mongoose schemas. In the case of `unique`, it appears that you have to write your own methods to query MongoDB to see if the value already exists. I suppose with 'required' Mongoose just needs to check if that value was passed in the constructor of a Mongoose model. But with unique, I don't understand the purpose of that.

```
userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

        username: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            required: true,
            validate: [validation.usernameValidator, 'not a valid username']
        },
         ...
```

in order to validate username, I have to create my own function = validation.usernameValidator to check MongoDB to see if the username already exists. So then what is the point of isUnique?

Comment: yeah I did! 'unique' is correct and what I was referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unique` will create a MongoDB ["unique" index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/#index-type-unique) on the property, preventing documents with the same value for that property to exist in the same collection.

However, since it's enforced by the database, the only way this works is by saving a document and catching the duplicate-key-error that MongoDB will return.

You can check for that error like so:

```
if (err && err.code === 11000) { ...duplicate... }
```

Comment: ahh, I see, so you still have to query MongoDB to see if the username is taken or not, but MongoDB will look in the index not in the document/collection. Originally I thought by using the unique property, that Mongoose/MongoDB would take care of the above. But it looks like from what you say that I still have to send Mongo a query. IMO that should be baked in?

Comment: @Olegzandr the documentation states that `unique` creates a unique index in your database, nothing more. Although I agree that it could be expected that it's Mongoose (and not MongoDB) that will handle uniqueness violations (although that could only work by Mongoose performing the query that you now have to do manually)